# This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values

Tags: spring, hibernate, mockito, junit4, spring-mvc-test

My Mock call is like below :

```
BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(url, 
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    BDDMockito.any(), 
    Response.class)
).willReturn(responseEntity);
```

but i am getting below errors . please help me out on this???????

```
4 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.esrx.aggregation.service.servicecaller.GetSpecalityInventoryItemsCallerTest.getSpecalityInventoryItemsCallPositiveTest(GetSpecalityInventoryItemsCallerTest.java:67)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@61375dff testClass = GetSpecalityInventoryItemsCallerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.esrx.aggregation.application.Main, class com.esrx.aggregation.application.Main}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:/application.properties, classpath:/service.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@351d00c0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@35d019a3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@78691363], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2017-12-19 15:59:53.085  INFO 10140 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5a62b2a4: startup date [Tue Dec 19 15:59:35 IST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3e6f3f28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you can't mix matchers with raw values. If you use matchers then you need to use matchers for all arguments. If you still want to match an exact value you can use the .eq() matcher:

```
BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.eq(url), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), BDDMockito.any(), Mockito.eq(Response.class))).willReturn(responseEntity)
```

Comment: BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), BDDMockito.any(),
    BDDMockito.<Class<Response>>any())).willReturn(responseEntity); working Great Thanks !!!!!

Comment: Good to hear! Accept my answer/upvote if it helped you!